# create all combinations of sorted arrays within set of values

Tags: python, combinatorics

I have p strictly ascending values, x0 < x1 < ... < xp

I would like to generate all possible arrays of size n filled with the above values for which a[0] <= a[1] <= ... <= a[n-2] <= a[n-1]. For example:

```
[x0, x0, x0, ... , x0]
[x0, x1, x1, ... , x1]
[x0, x0, x1, ... , x1]
[x1, x2, x3, ... , x3]

etc...
```

What would be the most elegant and efficient way of doing so?

Comment: Please clarify? `[x0, x0, ...]` is not ascending. Do you mean "non-descending" instead? Is there a reason the second line in your list wasn't `[x0, x0, x0, ... , x1]`?

Comment: yes: constant list is actually ok - i will edit to clarify

Comment: @Vincent The title still says "strictly ascending arrays". Maybe saying "sorted arrays" would be better?

Comment: good point! let me change this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Surprisingly easy ;-)

```
def crunch(xs, n):
    from itertools import combinations_with_replacement as cwr
    for t in cwr(xs, n):
        yield list(t)
```

Then, e.g.,

```
for x in crunch([1, 5, 7, 8, 10], 3):
    print(x)
```

displays

```
[1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 5]
[1, 1, 7]
[1, 1, 8]
[1, 1, 10]
[1, 5, 5]
[1, 5, 7]
[1, 5, 8]
[1, 5, 10]
[1, 7, 7]
[1, 7, 8]
[1, 7, 10]
[1, 8, 8]
[1, 8, 10]
[1, 10, 10]
[5, 5, 5]
[5, 5, 7]
[5, 5, 8]
[5, 5, 10]
[5, 7, 7]
[5, 7, 8]
[5, 7, 10]
[5, 8, 8]
[5, 8, 10]
[5, 10, 10]
[7, 7, 7]
[7, 7, 8]
[7, 7, 10]
[7, 8, 8]
[7, 8, 10]
[7, 10, 10]
[8, 8, 8]
[8, 8, 10]
[8, 10, 10]
[10, 10, 10]
```